# Adding global prototype function in TypeScript (Angular) causes error

Tags: angular, typescript, prototype

I am trying to add a global prototype function to my Angular-App, but it throws an error during compilation:

```
./src/app/helpers/functions.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: \src\app\helpers\functions.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at \node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:59:26
```

I import the file in the `app/app.module.ts` the following way (1st line):

```
import './helpers/functions.ts';
```

```
Object.prototype.clone = clone;
Array.prototype.clone = clone;

declare global {
  interface Array {
    clone(): typeof clone;
  }

  interface Object {
    clone(): typeof clone;
  }
}

function clone() {
  // creates deep copy of "this"
}
```

Maybe someone has an idea how to solve this? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you *"...make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property."* ?

Comment: Side note: Beware that if you extend `Object.prototype` or `Array.prototype` via direct assignment like that, it creates an enumerable property, which will break lots of code that expects objects inheriting from those not to have any enumerable properties. Some would say never extend those prototypes at all, but if you're going to, use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) with the default `enumerable` flag (which is `false`), so that the property isn't enumerable. But I'd be surprised...

Comment: ...if you don't run into a conflict with the name `clone`. If you don't know that **none** of the 3rd party code you're using has a `clone` property on an object somewhere, you're really better off just using a utility function you pass the object into. :-)

Comment: Thank you, @T.J.Crowder. It worked after I changed it in the `tsconfig.app.json`, but your notes became true after the prototype function was imported. So I will just export a clone-function :)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution now. It didn't work with `files` or `include` in the `tsconfig.json`.

Because the project was created using the angular-cli, there is a seperate `tsconfig.app.json`-file.

Just change it like this:

```
{
  ...
  "files": [
    ...
    "src/app/helpers/functions.ts"
  ],
  :::
}
```

As T.J. Crowder was pointing out in his comments to my question: Don't extend the Object or Array type like shown in my question. After the import of my function worked, I ran into the problems he described. Many custom libraries caused errors or weren't working the way they should. This was still the case after changing the property name to something else than `clone()`. So I am not gonna use the extension way but exported helpers functions.

Thank you for the notes!